# How does a PDF bookmark work?

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

How does a PDF document remember (bookmark) the last location / page which was accessed ?

A PDF document is able to remember the last read / accessed location even after the system has been shutdown and re-booted. Only if copied or moved to a new system, is the bookmark reset.

Comment: *A PDF document is able to remember the last read / accessed location even after the system has been shutdown and re-booted.* - No. Probably your **PDF viewer remembers** or your **PDF viewer changes the PDF** to open at the last location shown.

Comment: How does the pdf-viewer remember the last accessed page / location ?

Comment: *How does the pdf-viewer remember* - It stores it somewhere (probably mapping the paths of PDF files recently viewed to the respective last viewing location). Details depend on the very viewer.

Comment: ".. if copied or moved to a new system", there is your hint. The bookmark location is linked to the filename of the PDF.